# How can I add a filter for polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I need to add search by string in ActiveAdmin.
Something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Comment do
 filter :post_title, as: :string
end
```

If I have such an association:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
 has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

How I am to do this if i have two polymorphic associations? It is necessary to create custom filter?

Answer (score 9):

You might have to do something like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register Comment do
 filter :commentable_of_Post_type_title, as: :string
end
```

Note the `of_Post_type` with capital `P`, it helps Ransack to correctly specify the table names in SQL queries it generates.

The `title` in `Post_type_title` is an attribute of the `Posts` table. You can substitute it with anything else.

On Ransacking polymorphic associations, you can read more from the Ransack wiki here: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Polymorphic-searches